# Get root attribute value based on current node value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to grab the value of an attribute at the root node based on the value of the current node.

Example:

```
<root src="Bob" att="Mark">
<div>
<p>My name is <ref bar="src"/>.</p>
<p>My name is <ref bar="att"/>.</p>
</div>
</root>
```

My name is Bob.

My name is Mark.

I have this XPAth so far. It works up until I'm trying to test for the name based on the local attribute value provided in @bar. @bar has the name of the attribute in root where I need to pull the value.

This works...

```
/*/@*[name()='src']
```

This doesn't.

```
/*/@*[name()=@bar]
```

The value that I'm hoping to get is the value of @src, "foo" within the p tag.

I have to use XPath 1.0.

Edited:
I'm trying to get to the path of the ref tag wich should be the current node.

```
/*/@*[name()=//ref[count(preceding::ref)]/@bar]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please make it more clear what in this document is stable and given, what exactly you are "getting dynamically". `/*/@*[name()=@bar]` is obviously wrong, but what exactly are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Please give more context, say what programming language you are using XPath in, show that code.

Comment: I have to use XPath 1.0. I'm working in a CMS. The name is irrelevant to the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a path to the `bar` attribute in your predicate.

```
/*/@*[name()=../div/p/ref/@bar]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I determine which ref tag I'm currently in?

Comment: This matches a list of nodes which get selected in the document order. So in your example `src` is first and `att` is second. You can append positional predicates `[1]` or `[2]` to get first and second ref tag exclusively.

Comment: I have that much down, but I'm trying to resolve the predicate as well. I should be acting on the current ref node.

Comment: If you are calling this from XSLT code, you can use `current()` to refer to current node. `/*/@*[name()=current()/@bar]`

Comment: Unfortunately, current() is not implemented in the software I'm working with. I also tried "./@bar" and did not work.

Comment: @Jeff Actually, the name of the CMS and its language there is not irrelevant - that might be your only chance to get it working. Does the CMS simply allow formulating path expressions or anything beyond that, i.e. any higher-level code?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I can only do XPath 1.0 in this interface.